# I want to convert .mp4 to .ts using H264 at constant framerate 25fps

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, transcoding, libx264, 25fps

I've been trying to do this conversion for a couple of days reading through forums

***ffmpeg -i in1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -s 720x576 -vf "fps=25"-vsync cfr -b:v 2300k -acodec aac -b:a 128k out1.ts***

I've tried the below flags found in other forums
-r 25
-vf fps=25
-filter:v fps=25
-filter:v fps=fps=25

I then read the file using mediainfo and keep getting the same result;
Frame rate mode                          : VFR
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 46.875
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)

Comment: what is the `.ts` video format, and how does it compare to `.mts`?

Comment: @user610620 Please don't start a side-topic discussion in the comments. The difference between ts and mts is irrelevant here.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. That is, you have problem X, but you erroneously think solution Y works well. The error here is likely that you probably don't want a .ts file.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use ts, use mp4. MPEG-TS (.ts) and mkv default to VFR, while mp4 defaults to cfr. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate

That is this bug. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4768